# How to detect notifyitemchanged happen in Viewholder?

Tags: android

I want to run some method in viewholder class only if notifyitemchanged called from activity, otherwise don't want to call.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        public ViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            if(notifyitemchanged)
                runMethod();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should take a look into `RecyclerView` payloads. You can provide a change payload to your adapter when calling `notifyItemChanged` which you can then pass to your view holders.

Comment: You should take a look into RecyclerView payloads.....its new things from my my side
...,,,How to go with it ?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=recyclerview+payloads&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB811GB811&oq=recyclerview+payloads&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.2119j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is always the best place to start!

Comment: what is payload ?\

Comment: Have you read any of the articles I linked? They explain it quite nicely. It would be hard for me to give a full tutorial here when there are plenty out there already.